# How to cleanup asyncio.sleep() in a coro when te coro finishes before the sleep timeout

Tags: python, future, coroutine, python-asyncio, python-3.5

I'am not able to cleanup the count_timer (sleep) below, when this counter is interrupted and finished by another timer event (the stop_future).

```
import asyncio
import datetime
from concurrent.futures import FIRST_COMPLETED

DISPLAY_DT_TIMEOUT = 7
MAX_DISPLAY_COUNT = 3
COUNT_TIMEOUT = 4


def stop(stop_future, display_count):

    print('stop', display_count, datetime.datetime.now())
    stop_future.set_result('Done!')

async def display_dt1():

    display_count = 0
    stop_future = asyncio.Future()
    stop_handle = loop.call_later(DISPLAY_DT_TIMEOUT, stop, stop_future, display_count)

    # loop until
    while not stop_future.done() and display_count < MAX_DISPLAY_COUNT:
        print('dt1-1', display_count, datetime.datetime.now())
        count_timer = asyncio.sleep(COUNT_TIMEOUT)            # cleanup ??
        await asyncio.wait([count_timer, stop_future], return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
        print('dt-2', display_count, datetime.datetime.now())
        display_count += 1

    if not stop_future.done():
        # cleanup stop future
        stop_handle.cancel()
        stop_future.cancel()

async def wait_before_loop_close():

    await asyncio.sleep(10)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = display_dt1()
loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# this print shows the count_timer is still pending
print('tasks-1', asyncio.Task.all_tasks())

# wait for the count_timer to finish     
loop.run_until_complete(wait_before_loop_close())

loop.close()
print('tasks-2', asyncio.Task.all_tasks())

print('finished', datetime.datetime.now())
```

Result:

```
dt1-1 0 2015-11-10 15:20:58.200107
dt-2 0 2015-11-10 15:21:02.201654
dt1-1 1 2015-11-10 15:21:02.201654
stop 0 2015-11-10 15:21:05.186800      # stop interrupt
dt-2 1 2015-11-10 15:21:05.186800      # results in stop counting
tasks-1 {<Task pending coro=<sleep() running at D:\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:495> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>}
>>> tasks-2 set()
finished 2015-11-10 15:21:15.193669
```

**Update-1: cancel count_timer (wrapped in a future)**

```
async def display_dt1():

    count_timer_task = None
    display_count = 0
    stop_future = asyncio.Future()
    stop_handle = loop.call_later(DISPLAY_DT_TIMEOUT, stop, stop_future, display_count)

    while not stop_future.done() and display_count < MAX_DISPLAY_COUNT:
        print('dt1-1', display_count, datetime.datetime.now())
        count_timer = asyncio.sleep(COUNT_TIMEOUT)            # cleanup ??
        count_timer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(count_timer)
        await asyncio.wait([count_timer_task, stop_future], return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
        print('dt-2', display_count, datetime.datetime.now())
        display_count += 1

    if count_timer_task and not count_timer_task.cancelled():
        count_timer_task.cancel()
        print('check-1', datetime.datetime.now(), count_timer_task)

    if not stop_future.done():
        stop_handle.cancel()
        stop_future.cancel()
        print('check-2', datetime.datetime.now(), stop_future)
```

Result:

```
dt1-1 0 2015-11-10 16:44:29.180372
dt-2 0 2015-11-10 16:44:33.180908
dt1-1 1 2015-11-10 16:44:33.180908
stop 0 2015-11-10 16:44:36.181062
dt-2 1 2015-11-10 16:44:36.181062
check-1 2015-11-10 16:44:36.181062 <Task pending coro=<sleep() running at D:\Python\Python35-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:495> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
tasks-1 set()
>>> tasks-2 set()
finished 2015-11-10 16:44:46.181965
```

Comment: Can't you just call `count_timer.cancel()` when the `wait()` coroutine returns?

Comment: @Benjamin. I had to wrap the count_timer in a future to cancel it. But I do not fully understand the cleanup. See the above update-1 and Result check-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`asyncio.wait_for`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for) implements much of what you are trying to do. Combine it with [`asyncio.shield`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.shield) to prevent your Future from being cancelled when the timeout expires:

```
await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(stop_future), COUNT_TIMEOUT)
```

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, this goes in the `while` loop, replacing the call to `asyncio.wait`.

**Update** by voscausa: showing the code

```
async def display_dt1():

    display_count = 0
    stop_future = asyncio.Future()
    stop_handle = loop.call_later(DISPLAY_DT_TIMEOUT, stop, stop_future, display_count)

    while not stop_future.done() and display_count < MAX_DISPLAY_COUNT:
        print('dt-1', display_count, datetime.datetime.now())
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(stop_future), COUNT_TIMEOUT)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print('timeout', datetime.datetime.now())
        print('dt-2', display_count, datetime.datetime.now())
        display_count += 1

    if not stop_future.done():
        stop_handle.cancel()
        stop_future.cancel()
        print('check-2', datetime.datetime.now(), stop_future)
```

With:

```
DISPLAY_DT_TIMEOUT = 10
MAX_DISPLAY_COUNT = 3
COUNT_TIMEOUT = 4
```

Result:

```
dt-1 0 2015-11-10 21:43:04.549782
timeout 2015-11-10 21:43:08.551319   # count timeout
dt-2 0 2015-11-10 21:43:08.551319
dt-1 1 2015-11-10 21:43:08.551319
timeout 2015-11-10 21:43:12.552880   # count timeout
dt-2 1 2015-11-10 21:43:12.552880
dt-1 2 2015-11-10 21:43:12.552880
stop 0 2015-11-10 21:43:14.554649    # stop timeout
dt-2 2 2015-11-10 21:43:14.555650
tasks-1 set()
tasks-2 set()
finished 2015-11-10 21:43:24.558510
```

Comment: Thnx. Works fine. I updated your answer with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You've configured `wait()` to return upon the sooner of the timer finishing or the user cancelling the loop. It sounds like you want to cancel the `count_timer` in the case that it *wasn't* the future that caused the `wait` call to return. You can learn this simply by asking which of the two futures is done.

```
count_timer = asyncio.sleep(COUNT_TIMEOUT)
await asyncio.wait([count_timer, stop_future], return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
if not count_timer.done():
    count_timer.cancel()
```

Comment: I had to wrap the count_timer in a future to cancel it. But I do not fully understand the cleanup. See the above update-1 and Result check-1